# Correct way to update rules and configuration for a Prometheus installation on a Kubernetes cluster that was setup by prometheus-operator helm chart?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have configured Prometheus via helm chart https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator
I need to update Prometheus rules and configuration on the fly (hot-reload) but for some reason, it's not working.

I tried to edit the cofigmap for Prometheus rules but the changes are reverted as soon as I save the changes.
I have tried deleting the Prometheus configmap, it get's regenerated instantly.
I have also attempted to delete Prometheus pod itself but it also gets recreated instantly.

If the custom controller and CRDs are the reason behind this(i.e. rejecting the changes), what's the correct approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the better way will be using CRD [Prometheus Rule Files](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/pull/1333).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @evgenyl. This works perfectly for rules but I need to change Prometheus config as well. How do I change Prometheus config? These are custom resource definitions I see:
alertmanagers.monitoring.coreos.com     
prometheuses.monitoring.coreos.com      
prometheusrules.monitoring.coreos.com  
servicemonitors.monitoring.coreos.com

Comment: I know that there is this secret that holds the configuration **prometheus-<release-name>-prometheus-operator-prometheus** and I can get the configuration by 
**kubectl -n ams get secret prometheus-<release-name>-prometheus-operator-prometheus -ojson | jq -r '.data["prometheus.yaml"]' | base64 --decode ** but when I try to edit the config with new encoded value, it's reverted immediately.

Comment: Same issue in updating alertmanager config. I'm using prometheus-community/kube-prometheus helm chart

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is relevant to this deployment mode.  But we use the prometheus operator and there is a CRD for prometheus you can edit like this with the various settings in it:

```
kubectl edit prometheus -n monitoring prom-operator-kube-prometh-prometheus
```

This assumes the namespace is `monitoring` and the name is `prom-operator-kube-prometh-prometheus`.  You can also list them though with `get prometheus` or whatever to help track it down.

Answer (score 0):

you must modify CRD rule file, instead of configmap file

try

`kubectl get prometheusrules -A`

and `k edit prometheusrule ...`